# What's up with Hamaguchi's being in a different class?

Tags: teasing-master-takagi-san

I was initially wondering where Hamaguchi is in the Camping Trip episode S02E07

[image]

Notice we see the pairs / groups:

1. Takagi x Nishikata
2. Mano x Nakai
3. Mina, Yukari, Sanae
4. Kimura, Takao
5. Hell we can see 6 named characters in the front row all together: Mina, Yukari, Sanae, Kimura, Takao and Tanabe-sensei.

And then Houjou's not with anyone we know.

I checked the [fandom](https://karakai-jouzu-no-takagi-san.fandom.com/wiki/Hamaguchi) / wikia and apparently **all the main or supporting student characters but Hamaguchi are in the same class**.

[image]

**Question**: What's up with this? What's the difference to the plot if Hamaguchi is in their class?

You might argue Hamaguchi is a character introduced only later in (the manga equivalent of) s2, specifically S02E01, and thus is in a different class to avoid plot inconsistencies like 'Where was Hamaguchi during event X in s1?' But this doesn't explain Houjou who was also introduced only in s2, specifically S02E04.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

I'm not sure the plot changes much, but this is relevant for a minor joke in S03E06 where each class does their own thing for the culture / cultural festival.

> Houjou talks about dropping by Hamaguchi's class.

> [image]

> Hamaguchi doesn't want this. But Houjou goes anyway:

> [image]

Again, this is a just minor joke, not really relevant to the plot at least anime-wise. Hence, this is just a partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Actually in the same episode, there are 2 Houjou x Hamaguchi things. I'm not too sure of the details here. Maybe there's more in the manga.

1

Nakai comments about how Hamaguchi's food is cut differently or something.

[image]

[image]

2

They are [in the same folk dance](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67639/why-are-houjou-and-hamaguchi-in-the-same-folk-dance-when-theyre-in-different-cl) despite that they are in different classes.

[image]

As with my 1st answer, I don't think these are very relevant to the plot at least anime-wise. Hence, this is just a partial answer.