# Why are Houjou and Hamaguchi in the same folk dance when they're in different classes?

Tags: teasing-master-takagi-san

In S02E07, Houjou and Hamaguchi are in the same folk dance even though they're [not in the same class](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67617/whats-up-with-hamaguchis-being-in-a-different-class). Why? Does the folk dance combine classes or something?

Here's an image where they're both in the same folk dance. (Note: This image is marked as spoiler to hide whether or not they are holding hands at the end of the dance, if this image is takes place at the end of the dance.)

> They are indeed holding hands at the end of the dance.

> [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most likely they are combining classes. See Houjou's class photo at the start of the episode. There are 30 students consisting of, I think, 13 boys and 17 girls. (Even if I mistook some boys for girls, I think there are still more girls.)

[image]

But later Tanabe-sensei says there are more boys than girls.

[image]